# How to sort an array in reverse order using java?

Tags: java

```
package javaLearning;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

    public class myarray {

         public static void name() {
         String hello;
         hello = "hello, world";
         int hello_len = hello.length();
         char[] hello_array = new char[hello_len];
         hello.getChars(0, hello_len, hello_array, 0);
         Arrays.sort(hello_array, Collections.reverseOrder());
}
```

the "myarray" class is defiend in a main method of a testing class.
why does it give me a compile error when I try reversing the array?

Comment: And what is `haa`?  Please post your *actual* code.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code

Comment: since that apparently you're learning Java you should know that the official guidelines favors the use of all-lowercase package names.  Prefer *javalearning* to *javaLearning*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Collections.reverseOrder()` returns a `Comparator<Object>`. And `Arrays.sort` with comparator doesn't work for primitives

This should work

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MyArray {

    public static void name() {            
        String hello = "hello, world";
        char[] hello_array = hello.toCharArray();
        // copy to wrapper array
        Character[] hello_array1 = new Character[hello_array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < hello_array.length; i++) {
           hello_array1[i] = hello_array[i];
        }
        // sort the wrapper array instead of primitives
        Arrays.sort(hello_array1, Collections.reverseOrder());                            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error I get (assuming the original post had some typos) is that `Collections.reverseOrder()` returns a `Comparator<Object>`.

`Arrays.sort` (with a compartor) is only defined for descendents of Object so doesn't work for primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare `haa = hello.getChars(0, hello_len, hello_array, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Use Arrays.sort to sort in ascending order, then reverse the elements of the array (can be done inline with a simple loop).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that the code is not followed the standards of JAVA language.
Class name should always starts with UPPER case, and **sort()** of **Arrays** should not take primitive list of values as a parameter. change the 'char' to 'Character' and then use **Arrays.sort** method

Answer (score -1):

haa is not defined in the code you have shown us. That is a compile error.

Comment: Ok, I have fixed the typo in the code and it is still giving me an error?