# Reverse Sorting a Subarray in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, collections, reverse

My goal is to convert this  `Arrays.sort(nums, j+1, nums.length)` into a reverse sort. The only reverse sort information I can find doesn't seem to have the ability to sort a subarray.

And this gives me an error `Arrays.sort(nums, j+1, nums.length, Collections.reverseOrder());`

Comment: Relevant:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584579/how-to-sort-an-array-in-reverse-order-using-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Collections.reverseOrder() method only works for reference type, my suggestion is that your "nums" should hold reference type such as Integer, Double ... Or if you defined your own class, make sure your class implemented the **Comparable** interface